# CVS ignores .git folder

Tags: eclipse, git, cvs

I was trying to synchronize my local git repository to a CVS repository and everything gets synchronized properly, except for the .git folder.

At first, I thought all folders starting with a dot would be ignored, so I tried adding a .test folder and putting mock files in it. To my surprise, it is detected as a new folder, and the files inside of it are listed and ready to be synchronized.

How do I make CVS sync the .git folder? Thank you.

P.S. I use git locally to keep track of individual changes, and CVS for major milestones. They don't have to be linked in any form.

Comment: But you shouldn't though...

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not want the `.git` folder itself to be synced "as is" to your CVS repository.

When using git, the `.git` folder contains the version information, e.g. the content of all versions of all files in the repository (in a compressed format).

When you are syncing, the information in `.git` is used to populate the version control information in CVS. But CVS cannot read the information in the `.git` folder directly.

Syncing content of `.git` so that it would be visible in CVS would only be confusing (and dangerous if you tried to "sync back" that content to git, overwriting the contents of the `.git` folder in git).